# capture form submit finish event

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I have form which submits the data to server and server returns file to download. I want to display busy indicator while request hasn't started to return response. I have implemented busy loading functionality. But the thing is as it's not ajax call - how can I capture the moment when the form has been submitter **AND** server started to return response? I have googled and found solution with iframe. But maybe there are other solutions? Probably there is some kind of event like: onFormSubmitFinished.

Comment: How about `window.onbeforeunload` ?

Comment: if I understand correctly this event will occur before form submit while I need the event which will be fired after form submit and at the beginning of receiving response. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: How will event work if the context of `window` is lost ? `onbeforeunload` is kind of patch. You can hide the loader on `window.onload` event.

Comment: But then again this event will be fired when file is loaded. Probably this is not doable. I thought it is possible to make ordinary POST request and catch the moment when the response is returned/being returned

Comment: With conventional form submit, this is not possible as far as my knowledge is concerned...

Comment: @seeker 
It is only possible using XHR or websocket, one can catch the `submit` event and `e.preventDefault()` and then submit the data through XHR if one wishes for this behavior.